How to search in 1 excel column to return value from another column?
I need help to achieve what I need. I have data in 2 Columns (image attached), The first column (A) is for Master Agent and Column (B) is for Sub-agents. I also have a search box in Cell D1 and what I would like to happen is that, if I search for any names from Column B, it will return the Maste-Agent name where that sub-agent is under to.
Can you kindly help me with the formula I need to get this done?


You could try using the following formula:


=FILTER(SCAN(,A2:A13,LAMBDA(x,y,IF(y="",x,y))),D1=B2:B13)



Works 101%, Thank you so much for the help, really appreciate it. More power!

Glad to know it worked for you. Thanks!
